# SQL Query- Find in between date and time

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I have a table like this

```
|  EmpId   |  InTime          | OutTime          |
+----------+------------------+------------------+
|      101 | 01/02/2009 10:00 | 01/02/2009 20:00 |
|      101 | 01/02/2009 18:00 | 01/02/2009 20:00 |
|      102 | 01/02/2009  2:00 | 01/02/2009  2:00 |
|      103 | 01/02/2009  2:00 | 01/02/2009  5:00 |
|      104 | 01/02/2009  3:03 | 01/02/2009  5:00 |
|      104 | 01/02/2009  3:45 | 01/02/2009  7:00 |
|      105 | 01/02/2009 10:00 | 01/02/2009 22:00 |           
|      106 | 01/02/2009  3:00 | 01/02/2009  4:00 | 
|      106 | 01/02/2009  3:58 | 01/02/2009  4:10 | 
+----------+------------------+------------------+
```

I'd like to find the inbetween records.

My table has over 100k records.

Ex:

1. Check Empid - want to be same
2. Then Check the date & time, in first value is start at 10 and end at 20. and in 2nd record start at 8 and end at 20 same time. so 1st record end time want to replace with 2nd record end time(inbetween date&time)

Output like this:

```
| EmpId    |  StartTime       | EndTime          | EndTime1         |   
+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      101 | 01/02/2009 10:00 | 01/02/2009 20:00 |01/02/2009 18:00  |
|      101 | 01/02/2009 18:00 | 01/02/2009 20:00 |                  |
|      102 | 01/02/2009  2:00 | 01/02/2009  2:00 |                  |
|      103 | 01/02/2009  2:00 | 01/02/2009  5:00 |                  |
|      104 | 01/02/2009  3:03 | 01/02/2009  5:00 |01/02/2009  3:45  |
|      104 | 01/02/2009  3:45 | 01/02/2009  7:00 |                  |
|      105 | 01/02/2009 10:00 | 01/02/2009 22:00 |                  |
|      106 | 01/02/2009  3:00 | 01/02/2009  4:00 | 01/02/2009  3:58 |
|      106 | 01/02/2009  3:58 | 01/02/2009  4:10 |                  |
+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you actually want to replace 1st record end time with 2nd record start time as you show in your desired output and also assuming that all rows that share the same empid are overlapping I think one solution would be as simple as this:

```
    select empid, t1.intime starttime, t2.intime endtime t1.outtime endtime1 
    from table_name t1 
    left outer join table_name t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid and t1.intime < t2.intime order by 1,2;
```

Use a selfjoin to Add the Column With starttime of the successor entry. Use a left Join to keep rows without successors